# Parse string and assign to the same variable?

Tags: python

Is it an pythonic way to re-assign variables with values of different types?

I have a string of the form `k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3`, etc which comes from the command line. It is straightforward to parse it:

```
kvs=args.kvs
if kvs is not None:
    kvs = [(kv[0], kv[1]) for kv in [kv_str.split(':') for kv_str in kvs.split(',')]]
```

Since I came to python from strictly-typed languages the approach does not look really clean to me since it is re-assigned with a different type.

Would it be considered a pythonic solution of parsing the string?

Comment: Yes, it is usually fine on a case-by-case basis. I would consider this OK. This is really an opinion-based question though.

Comment: FWIW you can simplify: `kvs = [tuple(kv.split(':')) for kv in kvs.split(',')]`

Comment: None of the `v` values can contain a `:`, right? If they can, use `split(':', 1)`.

Comment: @chepner very useful note, thx

Comment: If you are using `argparse`, you might consider using a custom `type` to unpack the string *during* parsing, rather than after. `p.add_argument('--kvs', type=lambda kvs: [tuple(kv.split(':', 1)) for kv in kvs.split(",")])`.

Comment: @chepner I posted that as an answer before I saw your comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer:

That is fine a way to do it. Although you can just do `if kvs:` since empty collection types are considered falsey in Python (if that is appropriate for your case of course).

Long Answer:

This is really just opinion in Python world unfortunately. When coming from strictly-typed languages to Python you will see people do things that are discouraged or prohibited in a stricter language.

That being said I think it is always safer to avoid mutation whenever possible and to create a new variable if the type changes. In large codebases where args are passed around with no type checking, this approach can save you a lot of time debugging in the future.

Another way you may see this written is something like this that assigns the list object to a new variable.

```
kvs = "k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3"

kv_pairs = [
    tuple(kv_str.split(':'))
    for kv_str in kvs.split(',')
] if kvs else []
```

EDIT: fixed the code sample I posted

Comment: *"you can just do `if kvs:` though"* - I definitely wouldn't do that, in case you want to pass an empty string: `--kvs ''` -> `kvs = []` instead of `kvs = None`. If `--kvs` is not provided, then `kvs = None`.

Comment: Empty string/array/dict/set and None all are falsey. Try it out. Set `kvs` to None or some different empty data structures to and it will result in `kv_pairs == []`. If you wanted to do type checking before the comprehension was run for some reason, it would be better to explicitly raise a TypeError.

Comment: I mean OP is talking about command line argument handling, and those are always strings. As well OP's code leaves `kvs == None` if it's already `None`. I just updated my answer to show what I mean. No flag -> `kvs = None`, with flag and empty string -> `kvs = []`

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

It's not bad, but you might find it cleaner to parse it during argument parsing. For example in `argparse`, you can use a custom *type*:

```
import argparse

def kvs_string(kvs):
    if not kvs:
        return []  # Since str.split will return "['']"
    return [tuple(kv.split(':')) for kv in kvs.split(",")]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--kvs', type=kvs_string)

for args in [], ['--kvs', ''], ['--kvs', 'k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3']:
    print(parser.parse_args(args))
```

Output:

```
Namespace(kvs=None)
Namespace(kvs=[])
Namespace(kvs=[('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2'), ('k3', 'v3')])
```